# java android error with design excel file

Tags: java, android, excel, apache, apache-poi

Write a program on Android. In my program, I create an excel file. I have a problem with a design excel file.

error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Color;
```

code:

```
 Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
 Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Tets");
 Font headerFont;
 headerFont = workbook.createFont();
 headerFont.setBold(true);
 headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 17);
 headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
 CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
```

error on line:

```
CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
```

libraries:

```
 implementation files('libs/poi-3.17.jar')
 implementation files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.17.jar')
 implementation files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar')
```

Thanks for any help. Have a nice day!

Comment: `HSSFColor` needs `java.awt.Color` and `HSSFWorkbook.createCellStyle` needs `HSSFColor` because of creating the default cell style having black color. There are some approaches in the wild which workaraoud this by exporting their own  `java.awt.Color`. Seach keywords: `android apache poi`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. It is very easy.

1. Create a new project on Android Studio;
2. Go to a [link](https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/releases), and download the last version **poishadow-all.jar**;
3. This is the file you have to copy to the folder, as you can see in the picture below:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmHd8.jpg)

4. Go to File/Project Structure/app/Dependencies/"click to button«green cross»"/Jar Dependency/in folder *libs* choose library (**poishadow-all.jar**).  After click button **OK** and wait.
5. In the class where the file is created, you need to insert three lines:

   ```
   System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl");
   System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl");
   System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl");
   ```
6. Write your code.

For experience, you can to use the next code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl");      
        System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl");
        System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl");

        try {
            writeWorkbook();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void writeWorkbook() throws java.io.IOException
    {
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        try {
            Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");
            Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue("cell-1");
            cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue("cell-2");
            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue("Hello");

            Font headerFont;
            headerFont = wb.createFont();
            headerFont.setBold(true);
            headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 17);
            headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());

            HSSFCellStyle style = (HSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
            //   style.setFillBackgroundColor(new HSSFColor(new org.apache.poi.java.awt.Color(1, 2, 3)));
            style.setFillBackgroundColor((short)17);
            style.setFont(headerFont);

            Hyperlink link = wb.getCreationHelper().createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.URL);
            link.setAddress("http://www.google.at");
            link.setLabel("Google");
            cell.setHyperlink(link);

            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            sheet.setPrintGridlines(true);

        } finally {
            wb.close();
        }

        String excelFileName = "Test.xls";  //name of excel file
        FileOutputStream outputStream;

        try {
            outputStream = openFileOutput(excelFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            wb.write(outputStream);
            //   outputStream.write(cell.toString().getBytes());
            //   outputStream.close();

            File file = new File( excelFileName);
            file.getAbsolutePath();

            FileInputStream f = openFileInput(excelFileName);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So, I check program on the emulator, and I save the created file on the inner memory. I can to open created excel file from Device File Explorer. Way: *File Explorer/data/data/ «find your package project»/files* - here you see you created excel file.

Have a nice day!